# Usage of two DMA ADC channels in dual regular simultaneous mode STM32

Tags: stm32, dma, adc

I want to implement dual regular simultaneous mode of ADC1,ADC2 and two DMA ADC channels of stm32f303 discovery.

In CubeMX examples:

> Usage of two DMA channels (one for ADC master, one for ADC slave) is
>   also possible: this is the recommended configuration in case of high
>   ADC conversions rates and applications using other DMA channels
>   intensively.

According to AN4195

> When using the DMA, there are two possible cases: • Use of two
>   separate DMA channels for master and slave. Each ADC (in this case,
>   the MDMA[1:0]) must be kept cleared. The first DMA channel is used to
>   read the master ADC converted data from ADC_DR, and the DMA requests
>   are generated at each EOC event of the master ADC. The second DMA
>   channel is used to read the slave ADC converted data from ADC_DR, and
>   the DMA requests are generated at each EOC event of the slave ADC.

For 1 channel the code:

```
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc2, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, (uint32_t*)buffer, 3);
```

But how can we run 2 channels? HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA is for 1 channel as I can understand

Something like for independent mode is not working

```
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);
HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc2, ADC_SINGLE_ENDED);

HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);

HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1,(uint32_t*)ADC1_data,sizeof(ADC1_data)/sizeof(ADC1_data[0]));  
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc2,(uint32_t*)ADC2_data,sizeof(ADC2_data)/sizeof(ADC2_data[0]));
```

Comment: This quote from the CubeMx is definitelly wrong. How 10M requests can be less intensive for the bus matrix than 5M?

Comment: I got to this stage but found that the two DMA's had started at different times. I want to use this as dual simultaneous or dual interleaved. However when I do this (and I am setting data length to WORD) I get one data point transferred and the the DMA seems to hang. I have set EOC single conversion in the ADC as well. STM32F446RE

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, if this also applies to the F3 series, but I've written this toturial for the F103C8 regarding ADC dual regular simultanous mode:
http://www.bepat.de/2020/11/27/stm32f103c8-adc-dual-regular-simultaneous-mode/
maybe you'll find it helpfull.

To cut a long story short: I guess you are starting the ADCs the wrong way.
ADC2 needs to be started in normal mode BEFORE ADC1 starts with

```
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc2);
```

ADC1 is started afterwards with:

```
HAL_ADCEx_MultiModeStart_DMA(&hadc1, ADC_Buffer, ADC_BufferSize);
```

Comment: OK, doing this but I get just one WORD transferred and the DMA seems to hang. STM32F466RE

Answer (score 1):

Funny - great HAL library :).  This is my working code: interleaved mode - one DMA transfer half word per two conversions (master and slave). 8-bit resolution. Register version.

```
DMA1_Channel1 -> CPAR = (uint32_t)&(ADC12_COMMON -> CDR);
DMA1_Channel1 -> CMAR = (uint32_t)&obuff[0][0];
DMA1_Channel1 -> CNDTR = 1 * 1024;
DMA1_Channel1 -> CCR = DMA_CCR_MINC | DMA_CCR_TCIE | DMA_CCR_EN | DMA_CCR_MSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_PSIZE_0 | DMA_CCR_TEIE | (DMA_CCR_PL_Msk);

ADC12_COMMON -> CCR = (0b11 << ADC12_CCR_MDMA_Pos) | (0b111 << ADC12_CCR_MULTI_Pos);

ADC1 -> CFGR = ADC_CFGR_DMAEN | (0b10 << ADC_CFGR_RES_Pos);
ADC1 -> CFGR &= ~(ADC_CFGR_EXTEN_Msk | ADC_CFGR_EXTSEL_Msk);  // software trigger only, converting as fast as possible
ADC1 -> CFGR |= ADC_CFGR_CONT;
ADC1 -> SMPR1 = 0;
ADC1 -> SMPR2 = 0;

ADC1 -> SQR1 &= ~(ADC_SQR1_L_Msk);
ADC1 -> SQR1 &= ~(ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Msk);
ADC1 -> SQR1 |= (1 << ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Pos);

ADC2 -> CFGR = ADC_CFGR_DMAEN | (0b10 << ADC_CFGR_RES_Pos);
ADC2 -> SMPR1 = 0;
ADC2 -> SMPR2 = 0;

ADC2 -> SQR1 &= ~(ADC_SQR1_L_Msk);
ADC2 -> SQR1 &= ~(ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Msk);
ADC2 -> SQR1 |= (1 << ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Pos);
ADC1 -> CR |= ADC_CR_ADSTART;
```

DMA1_Channel1 interrupt is called when DMA finishes transfers.

Comment: Always drop the vendor libs when going on an adventure.